# Fetching registration IDs for GCM meteor app

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, meteor, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement push notification in my Meteor application for android devices.I am using this npm package called node-gcm. 
I have created an API project, got my project id, API key and everything. But the only thing that is remaining is the registration ids of the devices. I know that registration ids are the unique# for a mobile and an application.

But I am not being able to get these registration numbers. Whenever, any user sings up the app, I want to hit the Google API (or whatsoever) and get his registration number  and store in my DB. So that later, I can send him the notification.

This is my code in the server. I am testing it by plugging mobile device in android emulator in Ubuntu 14.04.

```
{{{

  var gcm = Meteor.npmRequire('node-gcm'); 

  var message = new gcm.Message({
      collapseKey: 'demo',
      delayWhileIdle: true,
      timeToLive: 3,
      data: {
          key1: 'message1',
          key2: 'message2'
      }
  });


  // Set up the sender with you API key 
  var sender = new gcm.Sender('########################');

  // Add the registration IDs of the devices you want to send to 
  var registrationIds = [];
  registrationIds.push("DONT HAVE ANY");


  // ... or retrying a specific number of times (10) 
  sender.send(message, registrationIds, 5, function (err, result) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("Notification not send");
      console.error(err);
    }
    else{
      console.log("Notification not send");
      console.log(result);
    }    
  });

}}}
```

So far the project is being developed and not in production.

Any proper suggestion is well appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I would register with [PubNub](https://admin.pubnub.com/#/register)(its free) and check the step-by-step tutorial for GCM applications written in JavaScript. The main thing as it looks now to retrieve the RegistrationID[s] is the following plugin code calls:

```js
  var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
  pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {
    'senderID': 'your_sender_id',
    'ecb': 'onNotificationGCM'
  });

  function errorHandler(error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + error);
  }

  function successHandler(result) {
    console.log('Success: ' + result);
  }

  function onNotificationGCM(e) {
    switch (e.event) {
      case 'registered':
        if (e.regid.length > 0) {
          deviceRegistered(e.regid);
        }
        break;
      case 'message':
        if (e.foreground) { // When the app is running foreground. 
          alert('The room temperature is set too high')
        }
        break;
      case 'error':
        console.log('Error: ' + e.msg);
        break;
      default:
        console.log('An unknown event was received');
        break;
    }
  }
```

[PubNub tutorial: Sending Android Push Notifications via GCM in JavaScript](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/sending-android-push-notifications-via-gcm-javascript-using-phonegap/#sthash.SSAkh5yL.dpuf)

Comment: Yes the only thing is to get the registration Ids of the users. And I wonder why no information is given in the internet for this. I am wondering if google has exposed us some link where I can simply hit their link with proper parameters and get the registration number for my app users.

Comment: The first 5 lines is what you are looking for or not?

Comment: But I do not want to use this pubnub

Comment: You don't have to use PubNub it was more as an inspiration to see how they do it.